# ActiveRecord date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, date-format

I've run into a spot of bother with date formats in our Rails application.

I have a date field in our view which I want to be formatted as ***dd/mm/yy***. This is how the user will expect to enter their dates, and the datepicker control uses this format.

However, Active Record seems to be expecting ***mm/dd/yy***.

If I enter ***01/03/2010***, this gets put in as ***03 January 2010***.

If I enter ***25/03/2010***, this gets put in a ***null***.

How do I get ActiveRecord to expect Her Majesties date format?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rails' DateTime tries to detect the formatting automatically. It will detect the following formats: `mm/dd/yy` or `dd-mm-yy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy/mm/dd`. You could monkey-patch `DateTime.parse`, but I would rather move this issue to the **View** of your application.

I always recommend to use `yyyy-mm-dd [hh:mm:ss]` as a string representation for a date. Check the documentation of your DatePicker if it supports multiple date-formats.

The jQuery date-picker for example has this covered with `dateFormat` (for the data that is sent to the server, set this to `yyyy-mm-dd`) as well as `altFormat` (for the input the user sees, set this to `dd/mm/yyyy`).

Comment: Hmm.. yes I can change the format in the view. I was hoping not to. It surprises me that ActiveRecord can't be localized like this..

Answer (score 12):

Add a file called `rails_defaults.rb` to `config\initializers` directory; with following lines:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%d/%m/%Y'
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]= '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Restart the server and you are good to go.

Comment: I cant get this to work. I have a new_rails_defaults.rb file that was created for me. Putting this in here does not work. Creating the rails_defaults.rb does not work either. Anything else I might have missed?

Comment: Yes, rebooted the machine just to make sure!

Comment: Does this rely on a specific rails version? I am on 2.3.4

Comment: Oh no I'm not... I'm on 2.3.5.

Comment: My solution will not work as it is. You need to override the to_time, to_date and to_datetime methods on the String class for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Date
  class << self
    def _parse_with_us_format(date, *args)
      if date =~ %r{^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$}
        _parse_without_us_format("#{$3.length == 2 ? "20#{$3}" : $3}-#{$1}-#{$2}", *args)
      else
        _parse_without_us_format(date, *args)
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain :_parse, :us_format
  end
end
```