# Rails: created_at returns in different formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Song model which contains hundreds of thousands of songs, when I do queries using AR the time format (when rendered to json) is like this: 2011-12-19T11:04:39Z.

When I execute a query using `Song.connection.execute()` the time format returned when rendering to json is like this: 2011-11-20 19:00:08.207467

I actually prefer the raw format which is returned from the `connection.execute()` call. How can I make it so AR consistently does not convert it? How would I set the correct time zone etc?

I basically want to make sure its always in the same format when requests either through a raw db call and through AR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the other way: I would prefer the format that AR converts to/gives you for free. The reason is that it would then be much easier to configure the format (for that, see eg  `to_formatted_s`).

For that to work, you'd have to avoid using `connection.execute`, and instead always use `YourModel.find_by_sql` - you would get an array of YourModel instances, with all the attributes correctly converted. For more info, see the docs: `ri find_by_sql`

Answer (score 1):

Edit your locale files and set the date and time format as you wish

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%Z"
      short: "%d %b"
      long: "%d %B %Y"
```

The syntax is that of [strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is likely due to the fact that ActiveRecord will create a Ruby `DateTime`, while `execute` would give you a plain string answer directly from the SQL engine. Thus, one is the default format from Rails, the other the default format from your DB.

[This](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/57923), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529990/activerecord-date-format) might be relevant.